# Methods to prove statements with floor (or ceiling) expressions?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, alternative-proof, ceiling-and-floor-functions

It is simple to prove by induction that
$$
\label{eq1}\tag{1}
n + \left\lfloor \tfrac 3 5 n \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \tfrac {n+2} 5 \right\rfloor
\;=\;
\left\lfloor \tfrac 9 5 n \right\rfloor
$$
holds for all integers $n \geq 0$: First substitute each $0 \leq n \lt 5$ to verify the 5 'base cases', and then substitute $n := n+5$ and prove that induction step from the induction hypothesis $(\ref{eq1})$.

The same goes for an inequality like
$$
n \;\geq\; \left\lfloor \tfrac 3 5 n \right\rfloor + 2 \left\lfloor \tfrac {n+2} 5 \right\rfloor
$$

My question: Is there perhaps another more 'direct' way to prove statements like these, avoiding checking multiple individual cases, and perhaps also avoiding induction?

Comment: My apologies for the very generic title, but I can't seem to find a better one. I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: You can get around induction by setting $ n = 5k+j$, where $0 \leq j < 5$. $\quad$ Generally speaking, checking cases is required (esp when there are multiple equality cases in the base case). $\quad$  If the bound is loose enough, then replacing $\lfloor x \rfloor < x+1$ could sometimes work (and obviously it won't work if equality holds).

Comment: just an additional hint on the above comment: since $j$ can take only few values, test them all to get rid of the floor function and replace the value by $0,1$ possibly $2$. The $k$ part can get out of the floor function as it is an integer. So no need induction.